# Ionic4/Angular lazy loading

Tags: angular, ionic4

What does this  statement mean?

loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'

For me, it means that: when I navigate to the tab1 route(path), angular router loads the Tab1PageModule module present in the tab1.module.ts file. This 
module will contain the routing informations to load (view) the component 
(page) Tab1Page.

Tab1PageModule  module will be loaded only when the route gets 
activated.

This is the situation:

```
 src/app/tabs-routing.module.ts:
    { path: 'tab1',
      loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule' 
    }


    src/app/tab1/tab1.module.ts:
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: Tab1Page
      }
```

is it right?

Comment: This is lazy loading in Angular. Yes, `Tab1PageModule` is not "loaded" (i.e. downloaded over interent) until `/tab1` is accessed.

Comment: and this syntax?  what does it mean?          loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)

Comment: That is the lazy loading part, have a read on this article: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules